# How can I set the file name field in JFileChooser to the file the user wants to save?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using netbeans. I added a `JFileChooser` and want to use it to save files to specific location that the user wants.
The user will choose from a `JTable` the file name that he wants to save and then the `JFileChooser` will open.
The problem is that I want the "File Name" field in the `JFileChooser` to be set to the String name of the file the user wants to save.
Is there a method in `JFileChooser` to do this?

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    fileChooser.setSelectedFile(file);
}
```

Comment: BTW - See [`JFileChooser.setSelectedFile(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setSelectedFile%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
package de.professional_webworkx.filechoosing;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFileChooser extends JFrame {

    private JFileChooser chooser;
    private JButton saveBtn;
    private MyFileChooser myFileChooser;
    public MyFileChooser() {

        myFileChooser = this;
        saveBtn = new JButton("Save");
        saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                chooser = new JFileChooser(System.getenv("user.home"));
                chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(<YOUR_STRING>));
                chooser.showSaveDialog(myFileChooser);
            }
        });
        this.getContentPane().add(saveBtn);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(640, 480);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFileChooser();
    }
}
```

Replace  with the String, you get from the user out of your JTable.